# Using a right front end framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks

I am starting a weekend project in rails. Since now i didn't have use any front' end framework so i am bit unsure about do i need it or not if yes then what should it be.
I am working on a project which is primarily single page application where user will interact most of the time on a single page and that page will be updated on user click only no automatic update. my question is

1. keeping in mind above requirments should i use front end framework
2. If Yes the which one

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need a frontend framework at all. jQuery should be enough if you are not changing too many components of page for a simple project.

Based on your exact requirement and personal preference you could use either angular or ember or backbone.
My preference is angular. Backbone is too much work. Haven't used ember yet.